# How to draw a line between an actionbar title and tabs?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have an activity with action bar.
The background color of Action bar and tabs is the same, so I need a little line space between them.
I am also using a custom tab view.

The style is:

```
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarCompat</item>
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTab</item>

    <!-- <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item> -->
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarCompat"parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#457AB1</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTabText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

   <style name="MyActionBarTab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bg</item>
   </style>
```

The screen looks like:
[image]

I need to have a little space between the title and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Code in xml After Your ActionBar Layout...

```
  <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
```

This will Add White line Between Your Action Bar & Tabs ... 
Hope this Will helps You...

Comment: there is no actionbar layout in my xml